MY SPRING SECURITY NO HACE LOGIN
Mi spring security no valida usuario y no hace login.
Adjunto código para apreciar tanto el controlador como la configuración
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("administrador/**", "/productos/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/", "/productos", "/usuario/registro", "/usuario/login", "/usuario/save").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("image/", "css/**", "vendor/**").permitAll() // allow get statics url resources with
                .anyRequest().authenticated()).formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("/usuario/login")
                        .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/usuario/acceso", true))
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


Ahora adjunto el controlador con el método para validar el usuario
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuario")

    @PostMapping("/acceso") 
    public String autenticador(Usuario usuario, HttpSession session, Model model) { 
        logger.info("Accesos : {} El usuario ha llegado al acceso", usuario);

        Optional<Usuario> user = usuarioService.findByEmail(usuario.getEmail());
        if (user.isPresent()) { 
            session.setAttribute("idusuario", user.get().getId());
            String username = user.get().getNombre();
            model.addAttribute("username", username);
            logger.info("Usuario de db: {}", user.get());
            if (user.get().getTipo().equals("ADMIN")) { 
                return "redirect:/administrador"; 
            } else {
                return "redirect:/"; 
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("El usuario no existe en el acceso");
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }


}

Tampoco me registra el usuario pero ni siquiera llega a ejecutarse el método del login dado que no me aparece la notificación del objeto logger.
